# Return JComboBox from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablemodel

so I've got a number of JComboBox's which make up a JTable. My question is; without having access to these JComboBox's directly, how can I obtain them from the JTable? Below is how I've put the JComboBoxes into the JTable...

```
TableColumn columnModel = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
columnModel.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));
```

...So I would imagine that you can return them by doing something like...

```
JComboBox retrievedDropDowns = (JComboBox)table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).getCellEditor();
```

But apparently not...

Am I far off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
JComboBox retrievedDropDowns = (JComboBox)table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getCellEditor().getComponent();
```

Comment: The method I've got is 'getTableCellEditorComponent()' which seems to have done it... So I wasn't far off at all LOL... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `DefaultCellEditor` in your columnModel then it will return a `DefaultCellEditor`  not a  `JComboBox`.

But you can use `DefaultCellEditor.getComponent()` to get the inner editorComponent.